# How to turn off location bar auto-hide on Tor Browser OS X?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

With my installation of Tor Browser OS X (ver. 5.5.4), the location bar always auto-hides. The only way to use it is to first hover the mouse where it would be, wait a second, then start typing a new URL. How can I force it to always show the location bar?

Comment: could you provide a screenshot? I am not able to reproduce your issue. Does this happen only in full screen mode? And what is your OSX version?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce your issue. To be fair, I wasn't even able to activate the auto-hide feature on OS X El Capitan 10.11.3. I believe that this dependent of your OS X version. (And Google seems to agree with me.)

On older OS X versions, you might want to try the following steps:

1. Launch the Tor Browser;
2. Type `about:config` in the URL bar;
3. Look for the `browser.fullscreen.autohide` entry, you can use the search box to find it quickly;
4. Set its value to `false`.

If that answer helped you, please, tell me your OS X version.